# Google apps script copy all rows of source sheet to last empty row of destination sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google apps script copy all rows of source sheet to last empty row of destination sheet when click submit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQSM.png)

Source Sheet

| Date | Region | Country | State | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-Dec-20 | Kapong Thom | Country1 | State 1 | Adidas |
| 22-Dec-20 | Kapong Thom | Country2 | State 2 | Nike |

Destination sheet (Result)

| Date | Region | Country | State | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Dec-20 | Kapong Thom | Country0 | State 0 | Puma |
| 21-Dec-20 | Kapong Thom | Country1 | State 1 | Adidas |
| 22-Dec-20 | Kapong Thom | Country2 | State 2 | Nike |

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your question, there are 2 pairs of `Source Sheet` and `Destination sheet`. Also, in your image, there are 4 columns. But, in your sample tables, only 2 columns are existing. What are the differences between them? And, what do you want to do the duplicate rows? And, after the rows are copied, what do you want to do about the copied rows? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how the image correlates with the 4 tables in your question.  Also why are the last 2 tables included in your question since they are simply duplicates of the first two rows.

Comment: HI Tanaike; I have updated the tables in my question. I want to copy all rows (2 rows) in source sheet to last empty row in Destination sheet. Thanks a lot

Comment: Here are some similar examples on web apps: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/172962/two-custom-fnctions-triggered-by-onedit-both-returning-errors/172967#172967   and also https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want.  It copies all of the rows in the source to the first empty row in the destination assuming that your are not using array functions in the destination because they can interfere with the getLastRow() calculation.

```
function copyAllRowsInSourceToFirtEmptyRowinDestination() {
  const svs = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid1").getSheetByName("sourcename").getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const dsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid2").getSheetByName("destinationname");
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,svs.length,svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```

If this is not what you wanted then please answer my question with some well correlated graphics and I might be able to come closer to what you want.

Comment: HI Cooper! I have updated the tables in my question. I want to copy all rows (2 rows) in source sheet to last empty row in Destination sheet. Thanks a lot